# Multi coloured action bar

Tags: android

```
<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/popupMenuStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.MyTheme.Widget</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">45dp</item>
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/PopUpText</item>
</style>

<style name="popupMenuStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="PopUpText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/tab_blue</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#0675bc</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:spinnersShown">@style/Spinner</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
</style>

<style name="MySpinnerLook" parent="@android:TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>

<style name="Spinner" parent="@android:TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyTheme.Widget" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:textColor">#0675bc</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/EditTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="EditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">#0675bc</item>
    <item name="android:background">#0675bc</item>

</style>

</resources>
```

Is there any way to create multi coloured action bar like

1. Action bar edit text background colour -yellow
2. Action bar edit text hint text colour-green
3. Action bar background colour -red etc.
   I am using the above the above code I am successfully changing the action bar background colour but the problem I need fully customized action bar. suppose action bar is having 
   1.edit text
   2.search view
   3.drop down list
   I need the above three should have three colours is it possible